# AWS Sam delpoy failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-serverless

I've create sam project file through `sam init`.
I've chosen "nodejs14.x" runtime and hello world template

`sam build` seems good.

But `sam deploy --guided` failed and error message is

```
Looking for resources needed for deployment:
        Creating the required resources...
Error: Failed to create managed resources: Waiter StackCreateComplete failed: Waiter encountered a terminal failure state: For expression "Stacks[].StackStatus" we matched expected path: "ROLLBACK_COMPLETE" at least once
```

In the aws cloudFormation console, I found that bucket policy creation is failed.
[image]

I've configured aws credential with administrator role(Permission: AdministratorAccess), so I bet, it is granted to create bucket policy.
Then, what's wrong with my project? Please help me.

Comment: I'm getting the same error in one account, and it magically resolved in another account. Try deleting the stack and running sam deploy -g again, just in case it magically resolves itself.

Answer (score -3):

Try deleting your stack in the CloudFormation console and redeploying it.